# How can I remove the broken (due to power cut during installation) kde plasma package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I was installing KDE plasma on Ubuntu but the power supply was cut off. when I tried to reinstall, an error occurred.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to use `sudo apt-get --purge remove kubuntu-desktop` but it failed. Using `sudo apt-get -f install` didn't work.

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
 kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
704 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/148 kB of archives.
After this operation, 808 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 293342 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also used `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq kubuntu-desktop` and it completed successfully but have no effect. I couldn't install synaptic and I also couldn't upgrade the package either. I also couldn't remove `google-im.service`

Answer (score 2):

Simply run:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

This will reinstall the package, and force the file to be overwritten. This issue often occurs when a file is moved from one package to another, and due to the repository not being fully up to date, or as in your case, an interrupted installation, the new file cannot be unpacked because it appears to conflict with another package.

What the above command does is cause dpkg to ignore any errors (through the use of the `--force-all` flag). You can also use `--force-overwrite`.